# Disabling basic authentication?

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee, websphere

How can i disable basic authentication in websphere 6.1?
I have written example servelet
In my war application i have defined something like this:

```
 <user-data-constraint>
          <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
       </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
    <login-config>
       <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
       <realm-name>Example login/realm-name>
    </login-config>



    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ExampleServelet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Now from UI any one with  the http://server/example/* can authenticate and there wont be any logout for basic authentication.

How can i disable this avoid this situation?Due to some reason i cant use form based authentication?

Answer (score 2):

@constantlearner: your question is vague. Do you want to disable authentication for whole application or just for a particular url-pattern.

for a particular url-pattern: just don't specify that in web-resource-collection tag.
for whole application, u can go to WAS console-> secure administration--> uncheck "enable application security" checkbox and restart app.

Answer (score 1):

Or if you want to be more specific with your authentication you can change your URL pattern:

```
 <url-pattern>/justServletNeedingAuthentication</url-pattern>
```